# scope issue with named pipes

Tags: c#, wpf, service, console, named-pipes

I have an app that has two components. One is a C# console app that will run as a service in production.  The other component is the UI which is a WPF app that runs as a system tray app.  [This article](https://erikengberg.com/named-pipes-in-net-6-with-tray-icon-and-service/#Start_NamedPipesServer_in_ServiceHost) is what I used to get off the ground. Both apps target .NET6.

I need to send messages through the named pipe, which is implemented with the [H.pipes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/H.Pipes/) nuget package, from both the console app and the WPF app. I am currently defining the named pipes object as a static variable in a static class so I can access it across multiple classes.  Like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsTapAgent
{
    internal static class Globals
    {
        public static NamedPipesServer pipeServer;

    }
}
```

The named pipe is initialized in the console app like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Serilog;
using WindowsTapAgent;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Reflection;

string logFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + "DrawbridgeAgent.log";

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            // add a rolling file for all logs
                            .WriteTo.File(logFileName,
                                          fileSizeLimitBytes: 2000000)
                            .WriteTo.Console()
                            .WriteTo.EventLog("Drawbridge Agent Source", manageEventSource: true)
                            // set default minimum level
                            .MinimumLevel.Information()
                           .CreateLogger();

Globals.pipeServer = new NamedPipesServer();
Globals.pipeServer.InitializeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
...
...
...
...
```

The actual code that accesses the named pipe is as follows:

```
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsTapAgent
{
    public class TapDevice
    {
        public RsaKey RsaKey { get; set; }
        //private NamedPipesServer PipeServer { get; set; }
        public TapDevice(AgentConfigInfo info)
        {
            Log.Information("In TapDevice Constructor");
            string containerName = info.RsaKeyContainerName;
            Log.Information("ContainerName: " + containerName);
            RsaKey = new RsaKey(containerName);
            Log.Information("RSAKey Public Key: " + RsaKey.getPublicKeyData());
        }
        
        public async Task<AgentConfigInfo> Register(RegistrationToken regToken, AgentConfigInfo info)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Information("-----------------------------Attempting to register------------------------------.");
                if (Globals.pipeServer != null)
                    Globals.pipeServer.SendMessage("Registering with Drawbridge");
...
...
...
```

NamedPipeServer class:

```
using H.Pipes;
using H.Pipes.Args;
using Common;

namespace WindowsTapAgent
{
    public class NamedPipesServer : IDisposable
    {
        const string PIPE_NAME = "drawbridgepipe";

        private PipeServer<PipeMessage> server;
        private PipeConnection<PipeMessage> connection;

        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            server = new PipeServer<PipeMessage>(PIPE_NAME);

            server.ClientConnected += async (o, args) => await OnClientConnectedAsync(args);
            server.ClientDisconnected += (o, args) => OnClientDisconnected(args);
            server.MessageReceived += (sender, args) => OnMessageReceived(args.Message);
            server.ExceptionOccurred += (o, args) => OnExceptionOccurred(args.Exception);

            await server.StartAsync();
        }

        private async Task OnClientConnectedAsync(ConnectionEventArgs<PipeMessage> args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine($"Client {args.Connection.Id} is now connected!");


            connection = args.Connection;
        }
...
...
...
```

The problem is that the TapDevice class is used in both the console app and the WPF app.  When the PipeServer object is accessed through the TapDevice class from the console app (where it's also declared and initialized) everything works fine.  When it's called from the WPF app, again through the TapDevice class, the PipeServer object is always null, and can't be used. How should I better structure this project?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had the client and server mixed up.  I needed to put the server on the UI side, then I can can create multiple client connections to it as needed.  This eliminates the need for the messy global variable that didn't work anyways.